# Half violin plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, violin-plot, statsplots.jl

I would like to plot a half violin plot instead of a full violin plot. Here is some reproducible code which creates full violin plots:

```
using StatsPlots
StatsPlots.violin(repeat(["A", "B"],outer=100),randn(300))
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it creates a full violin plot. In the [docs](https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/api/#Plots.violin-Tuple) I can't find anything about half violin plots. So I was wondering if anyone know if it is possible to creat half violin plots in `Julia`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional argument `side` defaults to `:both`, so to have a half violin, use `:left` or `:right` like this:

```
using StatsPlots
StatsPlots.violin(repeat(["A", "B"],outer=100),randn(300), side = :left)
```

Output:

[image: Half violin plot example]

Note that this behavior is not currently documented in the 'violin' [method docs](https://docs.juliaplots.org/dev/api/#Plots.violin-Tuple), but it is used in the [examples](https://docs.juliaplots.org/dev/generated/statsplots/#boxplot,-dotplot,-and-violin).